# Show that $\exists A \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall x$ $\in \mathbb{R}$, we may write $x$ uniquely as $x=a+q$, where $a\in A,q\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Not sure where to go with this one. Clearly will have to use the axiom of choice at some point. I haven't been able to think of a good example for the set $A.$ Once we've got that, it'd be a matter of showing that a representation $($as a sum, $q+a)$ exists for each real number $($which should be the case by construction of $A)$, and then subsequently that this representation is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: You need $A$ to have the property that if $a,b\in A$ and $a\ne b$, then $(a+\Bbb Q)\cap(b+\Bbb Q)=\varnothing$. Suppose that $x\in(a+\Bbb Q)\cap(b+\Bbb Q)$; then there are $p,q\in\Bbb Q$ such that $a+p=x=b+q$ and hence $b=a+(p-q)\in a+\Bbb Q$ Conversely, if $b\in a+\Bbb Q$, then it’s clear that $(a+\Bbb Q)\cap(b+\Bbb Q)\ne\varnothing$. Thus, you need to be sure that if $a,b\in A$ with $a\ne b$, then $b\notin a+\Bbb Q$.

Now note that $\{x+\Bbb Q:x\in\Bbb R\}$ is a partition of $\Bbb R$, so you can choose ... what?

(You can do this from a group-theoretic point of view, but it’s not necessary.)

Comment: Ah! Okay. So from each set of this partition of $\mathbb{R}$ I'll choose a representative element. Then I'll let A be the collection of these representatives. Hence, $\forall a,b \in A, a\neq b \rightarrow (a+\mathbb{Q})\cap(b+\mathbb{Q}) =$ ∅

Comment: @Yao: Yep, you’ve got it.

Comment: @Yao: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 3):

If you already know the axiom of choice has to be involved (and it does), there is little hope to being able to write $A$ explicitly.

Here is a hint: consider the quotient $\Bbb{R/Q}$.